# .net core 1.1 web app with Identity Framework "cannot restore...is not compatible with..."

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

My install of VS 2017 is up to date, and upon creating a new .NET Core 1.1 web app, with Identity (Individual user accounts) I get a slew of errors telling me that packages are incompatible. It would appear to me that something is seriously broken in the tooling for Identity Core. No updates are available. I've tried changing to different "netstandard..." and "netcoreapp..." targets in the .csproj but it doesn't fix it.

If I create a separate project without Identity, it restores and builds as expected.

Here's the full output with my test project:

> Error     Package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.3.0 supports:
>     - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
>     - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
>     - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
>     - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
>     - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
>     - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
>     - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)
>   Error       Package System.IO.Pipes 4.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package System.IO.Pipes 4.3.0 supports: netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
>   Error       Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common 1.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common 1.3.0 supports:
>     - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>     - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
>     - portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)
>   Error       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
>   Error       Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 1.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 1.3.0 supports:
>     - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>     - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
>     - portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 supports: portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)

Comment: Try clearing your Nuget cache with `dotnet nuget locals --clear all`

Comment: @TravisBoatman Nope, no change after running that.

Comment: Like @TravisBoatman said worked for me, clear the NuGet cache and run the web application after

Comment: @SamekaTV Did you run it in the context of your web project? I'm not sure if it works if your run it globally.

Comment: @TravisBoatman I did indeed run it from the app root folder. It obviously ran as expected because all refs were broken in the code, afterward. Restoring packages and attempting to rebuild the solution results in the same error.

Comment: @TravisBoatman Ha! Unbelievable. I deleted and re-created the test project I used to reproduce this issue, to begin with, and created a new one in exactly the same way. Now it works. I also went back into the project where I originally needed this and did the same thing, and that one also builds. One can only guess. Oh well, it's working...for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clearing NuGet cache did nothing. Deleting and re-creating the projects made the problem go away.